# Access DB Transaction Insert limit

Tags: c#, transactions, limit, ms-access-2010

Is there a limit to the amount of inserts you can do within an Access transaction before you need to commit or before Access/Jet throws an error?

I'm currently running the following code in hopes to determine what this maximum is.

```
OleDbConnection cn =
                new OleDbConnection(
                    @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\temp\myAccessFile.accdb;Persist Security Info=False;");
            try
            {
                cn.Open();
                oleCommand = new OleDbCommand("BEGIN TRANSACTION", cn);               
                oleCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();    
                oleCommand.CommandText =
                            "insert into [table1] (name) values ('1000000000001000000000000010000000000000')";

                for (i = 0; i < 25000000; i++)
                {
                    oleCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }                

                oleCommand.CommandText = "COMMIT";
                oleCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }
            finally
            {
                try
                {

                    oleCommand.CommandText = "COMMIT";
                    oleCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();                    
                }

                catch{}

                if (cn.State != ConnectionState.Closed)
                {
                    cn.Close();
                }
            }
```

The error I received on a production application when I reached 2,333,920 inserts in a single uncommited transaction was: "File sharing lock count exceeded. Increase MaxLocksPerFile registry entry". Disabling transactions fixed this problem.

Comment: There isn't near enough information in this question. What's the error? Where's the real code? How are you connecting to Jet?

Comment: More info added. Tnx.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there is in fact a limit. And you've reached it clearly. Per [Microsoft's documentation](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/815281):

> The error occurs if the number of locks required to perform a transaction exceeds the maximum number of locks per file.

At that link there are a couple of workarounds. The second one is more realistic, it changes the max locks temporarily.

Comment: Thanks for the documentation link.
I will break up the inserts into smaller batches of 500K inserts per transaction which should solve the issue for us.

Comment: @user986363, no problem, I'm glad I could be of assistance!

Answer (score 4):

I just successfully created and committed a transaction of 5,000,000 inserts on a table in an .accdb database. One significant difference is that I did not issue `BEGIN TRANSACTION` and `COMMIT` statements directly, I used an `OleDbTransaction` object instead:

```csharp
cmd.CommandText =
    @"INSERT INTO Companies (ID, CompanyName) VALUES (?, ?)";
cmd.Parameters.Add("?", OleDbType.Integer);
cmd.Parameters.Add("?", OleDbType.VarWChar, 255);
cmd.Prepare();

OleDbTransaction tran =  con.BeginTransaction();
cmd.Transaction = tran;
for (int i = 1; i <= 5000000; i++)
{
    if ((i % 100) == 0)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(i.ToString());
    }
    cmd.Parameters[0].Value = i;
    cmd.Parameters[1].Value = "Company" + i.ToString();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
tran.Commit();
```

**Edit re: comments**

After successfully creating and committing a 10,000,000-insert transaction, and verifying that a `.Rollback()` does actually *work* (good suggestion, neoistheone!), I checked the `IsolationLevel` of the transaction. The default `IsolationLevel` for the ACE.OLEDB driver is apparently `ReadCommitted`, which according [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.isolationlevel.aspx) means:

> Shared locks are held while the data is being read to avoid dirty reads, but the data can be changed before the end of the transaction, resulting in non-repeatable reads or phantom data.

Wikipedia has a good description of those different "read phenomena" [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isolation_%28database_systems%29#Read_phenomena).

Perhaps if I was to specify a more strict isolation level (like `Serializable`) I might hit the lock limit described in the question, although since these are all INSERT operations maybe the ACE.OLEDB driver just has to "hide" the inserts from all other connections until they are committed.

**Edit re: performance**

Since a fairly common reason for wrapping a large number of INSERT operations in a transaction is to get them done faster, I tested a batch of 100,000 inserts with and without the `OleDbTransaction`. (The prepared statement was used in both cases.) Without the `OleDbTransaction` the batch took approximately 36 seconds to complete. Enabling the `OleDbTransaction` with the default isolation level (`ReadCommitted`) reduced the elapsed time to around 23 seconds.

Comment: This is an interesting difference. It appears the transaction may actually be managed locally.

Comment: @neoistheone It certainly appears that the `OleDbTransaction` object is doing *something* to sidestep the limit that @user986363 encountered. I just tried a 10,000,000-insert transaction and it worked, too.

Comment: @neoistheone Yes, `.Rollback()` did work, at least for a "small" test of 100,000 inserts.

Comment: Okay, then *apparently* it's buffering those statements locally in the transaction and then executing them on the `Commit`. Wow, I mean to tell you, the stuff we have to work around in IT is quite frankly insane!

Comment: @neoistheone It does keep things interesting, that's for sure. BTW, I have updated my answer with a few more details.

Comment: Thank you for detailed feedback. I only realised now what you are achieving 4000+ inserts per second. I am only getting 360 at best using your code. Are you running special hardware ?

Comment: @user986363 No. In fact, those tests were done on my ~5 year old Dell notebook running 32-bit Vista.

Comment: We suspect either the antivirus or encryption on the company computers are drastically limiting our insert speed using access. We also get around 4k inserts when using external/non-company computers.