# How to increase maxlocksperfile for Access via C# and ODBC

Tags: c#, ms-access, ado.net, odbc

The basic problem is that the transaction is too big, but we really can't change that. The code (C# using system.data.odbc on an Access database) does around 10,000 updates in a single batch transaction. If it fails, it rolls back, per design.

The error message is "File sharing lock count exceeded" and recommends increasing the count in the MaxLocksPerFile registry entry. The default is 9500, and that is indeed about where it fails.

Problem is (a) we can't get it to work and (b) this application is deployed on customer sites where getting access to the registry is really hard.

DAO allows this to be set on a per-connection basis, but we can't find any way to do this from .Net. Hence this question.

Comment: Maybe the following link helps: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3389/Read-write-and-delete-from-registry-with-C

Comment: You may find [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19728132/2144390) interesting. Is the code using an `OdbcTransaction` object?

Comment: @rene: that's about updating the registry, which we know how to do but avoid because it requires privilege and manual intervention.

Comment: @GordThompson: good link, thanks. Not sure it solves anything, because we're using Odbc not Oledb. That's something we might consider changing, but it's intrusive.